# Nested for loop error

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does the outer for loop increment even after I set it back to the value of the variable? I am attempting to created a convoluted matrix with a 8x8 matrix and a 3x3 kernel to make a 6x6 matrix. The for loop iterates correctly, but `int i` is only set to the variable `threeRow` once then it increases it by 1 prematurely. `int i` is suppose to be in the same range throughout the whole set. So the first set, `int i` is only suppose to iterate `0-2` and the second set it iterates `1-3`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[6][6];
    int eightArray[8][8];
    int kernel[3][3];
    int sum = 0, product = 0;
    int threeRow = 0, threeColumn = 0, counterOne = 0, counterTwo = 0, column = 0, row = 0;

    for(int i = threeRow; i < 8; i++){
    cout << "______________________________________________" << endl;
        for(int j = threeColumn; j < 8; j++){
           product = eightArray[i][j] * kernel[counterTwo][counterOne];
           sum += product;
           cout << "(" << i << "," << j << ")" << " * (" << counterTwo << "," << counterOne << ") | ";
           counterOne++;
           // After it checks 3 three column it goes to the next row
           if(counterOne % 3  == 0){
              counterOne = 0;
              cout << endl;
              cout << "______________________________________________" << endl;
              break;
           }
       }
       // After it checks three rows the sum of 3x3 matrix within the 8x8 is found
       ++counterTwo;
       if(counterTwo % 3  == 0){
           i = threeRow;
           cout << "Sum of the matricies: " << sum << " placed into 6x6 matrix: " << "[" << row << "][" << column <<"]";
           counterTwo = 0;
           cout << endl << endl << endl;
           // Set the 6x6 matrix with the product
           a[row][column] = sum;
           sum = 0;
           // Starts reading the 8x8 matrix on the next column
           threeColumn++;
           column++;
           // Can only shift it 6 times before out of range
           if(column % 6 == 0){
               cout << endl << "Next set" << endl;
               // Resets the column back to 0
               threeColumn = 0;
               column = 0;
               // Starts reading from next row
               threeRow++;
               row++;
               // After reading 6 rows, breaks out of loop
               if(row % 6 == 0){
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or adding extra logging to establish the value of `i` at various points / iterations in your code?

Comment: I have tried that, but the problem is that I'm not sure what's incorrect about it. The logic portion of it works, and it's doing everything i want it to, but it just increases by 1 prematurely in the beginning.

Comment: you've got broken indentation can you fix that because it's unclear if you meant it or not. in visual studio Ctrl-A, Ctrl-K then Ctrl-F, reformats all indentation to be consistent. Just be sure that the close brackets for each scope are in fact connected to the open brackets that you think they are.

Comment: Okay i fixed the indentation

Comment: how does it not produce the right output? I'm looking at the output here. the first matrix starts from (0,0), the second matrix starts from (1,1) and the third matrix starts from (1,2) etc. You have to explain exactly how this is not to spec, because all we can see is that it's producing a bunch of matrices, not what you want them to do.

Comment: @JasonLang The first matrix for every set has the correct `int i`, so the first set is correct, it should be `(0,0) * (0,0) ` `(1,0) * (1,0)` `(2,0) * (2,0)` etc. After it got the sum of the first matrix, `int i` is suppose to go back to `threeRow` which for the first set is suppose to only range from `0-2`. But after the first matrix was formed and placed into `[0][0]` the loop starts `i` off at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: I got the issue, i'll write an actual answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that after you set i to threeRow, it goes to the end of the for loop, then increments i before you use it again. So it's always threeRow+1 when it's next used afrer being "reset".

You should simply set i to threeRow-1 instead of threeRow, to take account of the increment that happens to i because of the for loop.

However, playing around with for loops in this manner is not a great idea, it's prone to hard to track bugs and creates very confusing code that's hard to modify.

Generally, i'd suggest an inner loop that's always a nested 3x3 loop (for i=0 ...2 and for j = 0 to 2), and have a set of "outer" for loops that cycle through the base offsets. you then add the outer x/y to the inner x/y to get your offset values, and there's no need to get all "hacky" with loop iterators then.

Here's a reference implementation with nested loops instead of the manual tracking

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[6][6];
    int eightArray[8][8];
    int kernel[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            cout << "______________________________________________" << endl;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
            {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 3; jj++)
                {
                    int product = eightArray[i + ii][j + jj] * kernel[ii][jj];
                    sum += product;
                    cout << "(" << i + ii << "," << j + jj<< ")" << " * (" << ii << "," << jj << ") | ";
                } // loop jj
                cout << endl;
                cout << "______________________________________________" << endl;
            } // loop ii

            a[i][j] = sum;
            cout << "Sum of the matricies: " << sum << " placed into 6x6 matrix: " << "[" << i << "][" << j << "]";
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        } // loop j
        if (i < 5)
        {
            cout << endl << "Next set" << endl;
        }
    } // loop i

    std::cin.get();
}
```

This one would seem to avoid all the bugs and timing issues that crept in with trying to manually change the i/j loop iterators by hand.

Comment: Setting `i = threeRow-1` will set the first matrix to start at -1 rather than 0. Setting it to `threeRow-1` will make 5/6 matrices in my set correct, but the first matrix in each set will be off by 1.

Comment: i gets increased by one by the loop iterator so it instantly becomes zero again.

Comment: you know, you can actually *run the code* to check that what I said was correct before saying it's wrong ;) which is what I did. Making assumptions without testing is half the problem here.

Comment: you have other issues, with threeColumn not being updated at the right moment, but the above fix fixes rows at least.

Comment: I have no issues with the threeColumn, it checks through all the columns of the 8x8 matrix. I also did run the code where I set `for(int i = threeRow-1; i < 8; i++)` the for loop should initializes the size first, check the condition, do whatever is inside the for loop, then it increments. It doesn't increment by 1 automatically.

Comment: You probably have to completely move the code for i = threeRow. Updating i in at that position still gives some errors no matter what you do, that was the problem. Setting i=threeRow-1 gives the right starting point for every i in the set, except for the very first matrix per set, so i is in fact being updated too late. This is why I'm saying you're better off decoupling outer and inner pairs of loops. You'll end up with 4 iterators, but the code will end up much simpler and less bug prone.

Comment: I'll add a reference implementation showing what I'm on about, this should make it simpler